# Nodemailer sending HTML attachments but when opening the attachment its blank

Tags: nodemailer

Hello I am using the below code while sending the attachment in the nodemailer, the mail is getting sent with attachment but when I am opening the attachment , its not showing anything

```js
var mailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transporter = mailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'mailo2.abc.com',
  }));

 // send mail with defined transport object
 var mail = {
    from: '<john.doe@abc.com>', // sender address
    to: "<john.doe@abc.com>'// list of receivers
    subject: "Report for ABC Vital Business Function", // Subject line
    html: "<b> ABC Vital Business Function Report Attached</b>", // html body

    attachments: [{
        filename: 'Report.html,
        filepath:'.. /test-reports',
    }]
}

  transporter.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    }

    transporter.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Attachments object its path and not filepath. And make sure u give the exact file path in the filesystem.

```
{   
   filename: 'Report.html',
   path: '.. /test-reports/Report.html'
},
```